# Changing the permissions of a folder via the command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line-interface, file-permissions, ftp

I use FileZila,  and must give 777 permissions to a folder on my site.

This folder contains the database file.

FileZila tried changing the folder permissions, the command is running smoothly but the permissions are not changed.

How can I do this via the command line in windows (cmd)? 
I managed to connect, list and even send files via FTP using Windows cmd but I can not change the permissions of a file or folder.

Comment: What type of FTP server, what OS is the server running on?  Are you even permitted to modify permissions?

Comment: Windows' permissions system works differently from Unix/Linux's. What OS is the target file on?

Comment: OS: Windows. I am the owner of the folder

Comment: One of the tags on this post indicates the OS (Windows 7)

Comment: You can't give 777 to a Windows folder. Windows doesn't use the Unix Owner/Group/World permission structure.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a windows host, try icacls:

```
icacls foldername
```

this will print out the existing perms.

```
icacls directory_name /grant your_group:F /t
```

this will grant full control recursively to the directory to your group (or substitute your username)